# Defining function by name with arguments in struct

Tags: go

I want to generate a slice of functions with different arguments to pass to a channel to be run after reading from the channel. Is it possible to define the function by name and specify the arguments in the struct to be called later?

https://go.dev/play/p/G9I7JEbA-Ol

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

type ExecutionFn func(ctx context.Context, args interface{}) (interface{}, error)

type Job struct {
    Name   string
    ExecFn ExecutionFn
    Args   interface{}
}

func (j Job) execute(ctx context.Context) (interface{}, error) {
    fmt.Printf("Running job: %s\n", j.Name)
    return j.ExecFn(ctx, j.Args)
}

func someFunction(description string, i int) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println(description)
    return i * 2, nil
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.TODO()
    i := 1
    job := Job{
        Name:   fmt.Sprintf("Job %d", i),
        ExecFn: someFunction,
        Args:   "Multiply by two", i, // the values of the args to go to "someFunction"
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", job)
    result, err := job.execute(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Result: %v", result)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Package the function and arguments in a closure.

```
type Job struct {
    Name   string
    ExecFn func()
}

 ...

job := Job{
    Name:   fmt.Sprintf("Job %d", i),
    ExecFn: func() { someFunction("Multiply by two", i) }
}

...

j.ExecFn() // invoke the function
```